# Add results of a query

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have this query:

```
select 
sum(if(idcasa = 254, gcasa, 0)) as casa,  
sum(if(idvisitante = 254, gvisitante, 0)) as visitante
from partido
where  idcasa = 254 or idvisitante = 254 and  idpais = 1 and idtemporada = 1 and idcategoria = 1;
```

and what I want is to add the results, something like this:

```
sum(casa + visitante) as goles
```

Comment: `select sum(if(idcasa = 254, gcasa, 0)) + sum(if(idvisitante = 254, gvisitante, 0)) from partido ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is the query you want:

```
select sum(case when idcasa = 254 then gcasa else 0 end) as casa,  
       sum(case when idvisitante = 254 then gvisitante else 0 end) as visitante,
       sum(case when idcasa = 254 then gcasa else gvisitante end) as total
from partido
where (idcasa = 254 or idvisitante = 254) and
      idpais = 1 and
      idtemporada = 1 and
      idcategoria = 1;
```

First, note the change to the `where` clause -- the parentheses.  I am guessing this is the logic your really intend.

Second, it is simple enough to just add the values in an expression.  You *can* use a subquery to define the values first and just add them, but the expression is simple enough.  And, subqueries usually incur performance overheads in MySQL.

Third, I replaced the `if` with `case`.  The latter is the ANSI standard for conditional expressions.

Answer (score 1):

`WITH temp AS (
select 
       sum(if(idcasa = 254, gcasa, 0)) as casa,

       sum(if(idvisitante = 254, gvisitante, 0)) as visitante
from partido
     where 
         idcasa = 254 or idvisitante = 254 
         and  idpais = 1 
         and idtemporada = 1 
         and idcategoria = 1
)
SELECT  sum(casa + visitante) as goles FROM temp;`